# String comparison over two columns does not return If statement result

Tags: excel, vba

I've been successful in getting this string comparison to work with one column. I've expanded the range to two columns and it appears when viewing the locals window that the comparison is taking place. For reasons I've not been able to decipher though the if statement to change the color of the cell if the string comparison is positive does not occur.

Not getting any errors, but also not getting any response.

I've stepped through and watched the local window and everything I've observed there tells me the that the comparison is being made so I'm somewhat baffled as to what could be missing.

```
Sub ColourDuplicateNameTwoCol() 'Work in progress

    Dim baseName As Range
    Dim allName As Range 
    Dim cell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
            Set baseName = Range("c1")
            Set allName = Range("a1:b7")

            For Each cell In allName.cells
                If StrComp(baseName.Value, cell.Value, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                  cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                End If
            Next cell

    End With

End Sub
```

Here is the one column working version I mention

```
Sub ColourDuplicateName() 'Works 

Dim baseName As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
Set baseName = .Range("b1")

For I = 1 To 7
    If StrComp(baseName.Value, cells(I, 1).Value, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
    cells(I, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next I

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Quote: "For reasons I've not been able to decipher though the if statement to change the color of the cell if the string comparison is positive does not occur.". Huh?

Comment: I'm not sure what to add for you.  When the comparison comes back positive, as in the two words (strings) match the color of the matching cell should change to yellow.

Comment: There is a grammatical error there so the sentence does not read correctly. What you have now followed up with in your comment makes more sense. (It was specifically " though the if statement to change the color")

Comment: Have you tried either of these syntaxes too? https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/background-colors.html I am not sure if vbYellow is valid. This may help with RGB - just move cursor over color you like to get RGB numbers. https://www.colorspire.com/rgb-color-wheel/ I may be wrong... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/color-constants

Comment: you are doing this/looking at sheet1 right?

Comment: Yes to the last comment. I've suspected it may be the use of color but I've used the same line to achieve a change in color when I'm only searching one column and there is not an issue.

Comment: I find it rather mystifying. There's nothing odd like macros disabled on document. The code looks good to me too.

Comment: Have you done something like put an alert inside if inside of for loop. E.G: `MsgBox "Eureka"`. See if you get the alert as positive feedback?

Comment: I don't think this is your problem, but you are not using your `With Block` at all since non of your ranges are qualified. `Set baseName = Range("c1")` needs to be `Set baseName = .Range("c1")` (Notice the dot before Range).

Comment: Can you verify that you don't have any other conditional formatting rules that are taking precedent? I would try to copy your values and code to a new workbook and test again. This has only happened once to me, but I spent hours debugging code that seemed to be fine to no avail - turns out the workbook was corrupted and the code was fine - I just needed to start over with a new book.

Comment: JGFMK - I'll try the msg box, but I think urdearboy is on to something.  I've copied the two column code to a new workbook and still no effect, but perhaps more interesting, when I copy and paste the one column working code to a new book, it no longer works ? I think the code as it is written is correct, I believe there is some kind of block in place, but I'll have to do a few more tests to see what happens.  I did not know the need for .Range when using With Blocks, thanks for that.

Comment: @urdearboy - nice spot. It's been so long since I've done VBA in anger. I remember it from Windows XP days! I use a MBP and OSX Mojave these days - and the VBA implementation on that is bad in Office 365. I think allname needs the dot notation too. But cell would be ok without it, as it's a temp variable

Comment: So what I've discovered is as follows - when I'm using ColourDuplicateNameTwoCol() the issue appears to be that the code is not reading the string content of the cells in the range. I found this out by accident when I left a cell, in the 2nd column of the range blank. Ran the code and the blank cell filled in. This strongly hints that the issue is the code is not recognizing the String in the range, but does  recognize the string in cell c1 to do the comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interpretation of the return value from `StrComp` is incorrect.  Check VBA HELP.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ColourDuplicateNameTwoCol() 'Work in progress

    Dim baseName As Range
    Dim allName As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
            Set baseName = .Range("c1")
            Set allName = .Range("a1:b7")

            For Each cell In allName.Cells
                If StrComp(baseName.Value, cell.Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                  cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                End If
            Next cell

    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

The above code, which merely shows the `StrComp` problem you have run into, is not very dynamic.  You would have to add code to remove the color, and then add it back, should `baseName` change.  You could, of course, do this with an event Macro.

However, a more dynamic method would be to just set up Conditional Formatting. You would only have to do this once, and it could accomplish the same.

To do this in VBA code, for example:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ColourDuplicateNameTwoCol() 'Work in progress

    Dim baseName As Range
    Dim allName As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
            Set baseName = .Range("c1")
            Set allName = .Range("a1:b7")
    End With

    With baseName.FormatConditions
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlCellValue, _
            Operator:=xlEqual, _
            Formula1:=baseName
        .Item(1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End With

End Sub
```

*This code will need to be modified if you have other `FormatConditions` for `allNames` which you want to retain.*

Comment: Interesting, and thanks for pointing that out regarding StrComp.  I'll look deeper at what you have posted here as that was the long term direction, this was a step along the way that I got badly hung up.  The use of 'Item' is new to me, I've not come across it to date, but always good to see new terms used to expand my knowledge base.  Great example how the difference between a 0 and a 1 can cause success or failure.